# Placing multiple variables in a String ready for SQL Prepared Statement - Cleanest way

Tags: java, sql, string, formatting, prepared-statement

I have to build an SQL string for a prepared statement, it needs multiple variables inserting.  What is the cleanest way to do this?

Raw SQL for MYSQL database, variables in bold

> INSERT INTO **output**(**their_sku**, **their_description**,
> **net_cost**) SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM **import**

The names come from Enums that could possibly need modifying, hence no hard coding table names or columns.

All my attempts look messy, and coming from Python I am missing the fStrings.  Attempts below.

```
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO %s(%s, %s, %s) SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM %s", Tables.OUTPUT, OutputTableFields.THEIR_SKU, OutputTableFields.THEIR_DESCRIPTION, OutputTableFields.NET_COST, Tables.IMPORT);
```

Quite unreadable

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + Tables.OUTPUT + "(" + OutputTableFields.THEIR_SKU + ", " + OutputTableFields.THEIR_DESCRIPTION + ", " + OutputTableFields.NET_COST + ") SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM " + Tables.IMPORT"
```

At least the SQL and Enums are in order but it looks awful

Is there a best practice way of setting this out?

Thankyou.

Comment: Using plain JDBC can lead to long lines. Nowdays you typically extract all the SQL code from Java by using an ORM instead.

Comment: Using `java`, I'd probably take a look at `hibernate` https://hibernate.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this helps too much in your case, but you might also consider using text blocks available since JDK15. A text block makes it neater to specify a long string which can be broken up into many lines.

You can combine with `s.formatted(args...)` which is equivalent of `String.format(s, args...)` as follows:

```
String sql = """
  INSERT INTO %s(%s, %s, %s) 
  SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM %s
  """
  .formatted(Tables.OUTPUT, OutputTableFields.THEIR_SKU, OutputTableFields.THEIR_DESCRIPTION, OutputTableFields.NET_COST, Tables.IMPORT);

=> sql is:
"INSERT INTO blah(blah, blah, blah)
SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM blah
"
```

Note that the above introduces line break, if not wanting these you can escape by adding a trailing `\` like this:

```
String sql = """
  INSERT INTO %s(%s, %s, %s) \
  SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM %s\
  """
  .formatted(Tables.OUTPUT, OutputTableFields.THEIR_SKU, OutputTableFields.THEIR_DESCRIPTION, OutputTableFields.NET_COST, Tables.IMPORT);

=> sql is:
"INSERT INTO blah(blah, blah, blah) SELECT product_code, product_description, net_cost FROM blah"
```

You could also use static imports to shorten the `formatted(...)` part or use resource bundle files for the text.